# ninja - Important or can it be disabled?

Tags: security

I have a process called ninja running continuously in the background on my machine running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. The man page says that it is 'Privilege escalation detection system for GNU/Linux'. I have ufw enabled on my system. Do I need ninja or can I disable it?

Comment: Whether or not you need it, depends on the context. Are you using desktop machine or a server with sensitive data on it ? Do you need security hardening for your machine ? It does not seem like you have installed the package yourself but it may have gotten it as dependency for some other software. So consider your needs first, then decide

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy - Thanks for the quick reply. You're right I didn't install the package myself. It was probably installed by some other software. Good advice - I will leave it be for now.

Comment: Do a dry run(without sudo) ````apt-get -s remove  [name] ```` to see the effects.